# How to get number of cloud run container using postman

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, postman-collection-runner, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to fetch number of GCP Cloud Run container count using postman but unable to find it.

can you please help in constructing postman request.

Thanks in advance.

run.googleapis.com/container/instance_count
Trying this

Answer (score 0):

If you have the parameters below, you could try

```
GET https://run.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{REGION}/services/{SERVICE_NAME}
```